# How to block a specific user from seeing my files over the local network with win 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

Im looking to block a specific IP from accessing my files over our network.
The issue is that the root folders should be shared with all other PCs.

I basically need to find a way to block that specific pc from accessing my files...

Comment: So just to verify I understand your question.  You are looking for a way to, not share with a specific PC, but share with any other PC?  You can adjust the sharing permissions on a folder you have shared, and only give permissions to those accounts on other accounts, you specifically choose.

Comment: Yup but the issue is that i dont have allother accounts as we have alot of pcs onsite and even remotely....

Comment: This is a corporate network?

Comment: Yes. Ive tried to disable sharing but were requiredto haveit enabled.

Comment: @jester3k - If you are required to have it enabled, then you will be unable to achieve your task, of not sharing it with an unknown amount fo computers.  If you have the power I suggest sharing files with people outside of your network, is something you should addressed, by something other then file sharing.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Windows firewall rules to do that. Just use Windows firewall advanced properties. You can block any IP for incoming connections.

Comment: Be aware that if the user with the PC in question spoofs the MAC address and gets a new IP, you're exposed to them again. On most networks this is trivial - a seriously locked-down corporate net might make it difficult, but in that case you'd probably be asking those folks to shut down the user in question, not us.

Comment: Ok great, is there a way to leave one folder that can be shared with that computer?

Comment: If you block IP - no, there is now way to still share a folder.

Comment: Any chance youd explain how to do it?

Comment: In Windows firewall advanced settings add a rule for this IP/computer that you block all incoming connections.

Comment: Im trying right now but i cant seem to find where to input the ip address

Comment: Option "non-standard", TCP, all ports, then you will have possibility to add IP addresses.